# Convert Uint8List to File

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm using Image Picker web which works well. I can display image in `Image.memory()`, but this image in format Uintlist8.  For save in storage need format `File`, my issue is how to save an image in **Firebase Storage**.

Web image picker:

```
class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Uint8List _image;

  getImage() async {
    Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);
    if (tempImg != null) {
      setState(() {
      _image = tempImg;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Please Try ....

```
final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  Uint8List _image;
 getImage() async {
 Uint8List tempImg = await ImagePickerWeb.getImage(asUint8List: true);
 if (tempImg != null) {
  setState(() {
  _image = tempImg;
  final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
  final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.jpg').create();
  file.writeAsBytesSync(_image);
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Now doesnt diplay image in `Image,memory()`

Comment: You can try Image.file(file); to display the image.

Comment: I had tried it too, file is in setState so i create `File img` and did this file = img. After that in Image.file(img). Its doesnt display. i hope you have any way

Comment: Wotrked like a charm! Needed to get the path string from a Uin8List image and this was the unic solution I found.

Comment: Does this answer the question?  `path_provider` does not work for web.  You get `MissingPluginException`

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been searching for it almost 1 hour

Comment: await getTemporaryDirectory(); this is not supported on flutter web.. because path_provider is not supported yet on flutter web.