# I added Watermaek over image but image is not loading

Tags: flutter, watermark

I am using watermark over image i have seen https://medium.com/flutter-community/add-watermark-over-image-in-flutter-e7353e3cf603 this article for watermark ! all is good but i cant be able to load �PNG image ! plz help me to get out of this

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

import 'package:image/image.dart' as ui;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

File _originalImage;
File _watermarkImage;
File _watermarkedImage;
final picker = ImagePicker();

Future getOriginalImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  _originalImage = File(pickedFile.path);
});
}

Future getWatermarkImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  _watermarkImage = File(pickedFile.path);
});
}

@override
void initState() {

super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Watermark Example"),),
    body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
       //<--------------- select original image ---------------->
          _originalImage==null? FlatButton(
            child: Text("Select Original Image"),
            onPressed: getOriginalImage,
          )
              : Image.file(_originalImage),

             //<--------------- select watermark image ---------------->
           _watermarkImage==null? FlatButton(
            child: Text("Select Watermark Image"),
            onPressed: getWatermarkImage,
          )
              : Image.file(_watermarkImage),

          SizedBox(height: 50,),
             //<--------------- apply watermark over image ---------------->
          (_originalImage!=null)&&(_watermarkImage!=null)?
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Apply Watermark Over Image"),
            onPressed: () async {

              ui.Image originalImage = ui.decodeImage(_originalImage.readAsBytesSync());
              ui.Image watermarkImage = ui.decodeImage(_watermarkImage.readAsBytesSync());

              // add watermark over originalImage
              // initialize width and height of watermark image
              ui.Image image = ui.Image(160, 50);
              ui.drawImage(image, watermarkImage);

              // give position to watermark over image
              // originalImage.width - 160 - 25 (width of originalImage - width of watermarkImage - extra margin you want to give)
              // originalImage.height - 50 - 25 (height of originalImage - height of watermarkImage - extra margin you want to give)
              ui.copyInto(originalImage,image, dstX: originalImage.width - 160 - 25, dstY: originalImage.height - 50 - 25);


              // for adding text over image
              // Draw some text using 24pt arial font
              // 100 is position from x-axis, 120 is position from y-axis
              ui.drawString(originalImage, ui.arial_24, 100, 120, 'Think Different');


              // Store the watermarked image to a File
              List<int> wmImage = ui.encodePng(originalImage);
              setState(() {
                _watermarkedImage = File.fromRawPath(Uint8List.fromList(wmImage));
              });

            },
          )
              : Container(),

          //<--------------- display watermarked image ---------------->
          _watermarkedImage!=null?
          Image.file(_watermarkedImage) 
                 // HOW TO LOAD THIS "�PNG" IMAGE     
              : Container(),


        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

}
```

after the run i am getting Error : Cannot open file, path = '�PNG

IHDR  b     q�+ ��IDATx�� ��8�%��4w�̪��_�-27������2��H���*���gT%�Ҝ�P�a������k�u۶����{�o�������9||�������o8�������߿���?��s|���eYj��Q�m����  㖶}��}~}���RJ�����}��ѷ�xr�r2�>~����������`ܕKO^J��K��s����Z^s�!����ל;ζm�G&0��e�G$g��q�˸�V�x�������e��,@����md�t�hom�9�"��x����˘H�|���J)2�1�R��Z� �|�3㧆c|O�WN(c��D���z�����x�Ǚ�䢞vN !X

Answer (score 0):

Even if I'm not sure this is your problem, I'd point out that the result of `ui.encodePng(originalImage)` is an `Uint8List`.

So, I'd suggest you to change your code to:

```dart
Uint8List wmImage = ui.encodePng(originalImage);
setState(() {
  _watermarkedImage = File.fromRawPath(wmImage);
});
```

I'm quite sure your error is the result of opening the bytes of a PNG as a file, while you only have the bytes of a PNG.

#### If that's still not working

As stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60507299/7370692), you may need to save your resulted file to a temporary file, in order to be able to load it from the raw path.

In that case, you should write:

```dart
Uint8List wmImage = ui.encodePng(originalImage);

final String tempDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
final File tempFile = File("$tempDir/tempImage.png");
file.writeAsBytesSync(wmImage);

setState(() {
  _watermarkedImage = tempFile;
});
```

This will add some milliseconds to computation time, but it's more stable and robust as keeping file only in memory.

Comment: Still same issue : Cannot open file, path = '�PNG